# Animate fade-out for drawings

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation

I have a view where the user can draw. What I want is that, the strokes that were drawn by the user must slowly fade-out in the order that they were drawn. Any advice ?

Comment: If you give more details of what is what you want would it be great.

Comment: @user2195741 , suppose the user draws a line from top to bottom, the line must fade out from top to bottom after few seconds.

Comment: How are you drawing the strokes right now? Quartz2D?

Answer (score 0):

JYou can try pluging in a `AnimationFadeOut` and also set a duration to it. Here is a code snippet for that. Let me know if this helps you out.

```
-(void)fadeOut:(UIView*)viewToDissolve withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration   andWait:(NSTimeInterval)wait
 {
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade Out" context:nil];

    // wait for time before begin
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:wait];

    // druation of animation
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    viewToDissolve.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
  }
```

Rather than uiview you can use your action to fade out.

Answer (score 0):

For what you're asking, you could simply add a stroke as a subview, then use a cross fade transition.

```
[drawingView addSubView:strokeView];
[UIView transitionWithView:strokeView duration:0.2f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:NULL completion:NULL];
```

For something like this (showing a drawing being completed), I would personally capture the touch points and time offsets to animate the drawing of each point at the speed of the drawer. More code, but a stylistic choice.

Comment: I dont want the entire stroke to fade out at once. I want it to fade-out in the order ( the same way ) that it was drawn @Keller